# Custom Migration corrupts db

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, core-data-migration

When I try to migrate my old db to a new db, it is all done correctly. But when I try to access the db, it says its corrupted or malformed. It happens only in iOS11.

I get this error -

```
error: exception handling request: <NSSQLRelationshipFaultRequestContext: 0x1c4cbc9e0> , Fatal error.  The database at /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/743F0953-2F57-4B9F-931A-0E0AEF9E8D0A/Documents/Main.db is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed' with userInfo of {
    NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/743F0953-2F57-4B9F-931A-0E0AEF9E8D0A/Documents/Main.db";
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 11;
}
```

When I try accessing db, I get -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'
```

This is my code of migration -

```
NSError     *error = nil;
    NSMappingModel                  *mapping = [NSMappingModel inferredMappingModelForSourceModel: oldModel destinationModel: self error: &error];
    if (error) {
        LOG(@"Error while inferring mapping model: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }
    NSString                        *newContextPath = [contextPath stringByAppendingPathExtension: @"tmp"];
    NSValue                         *classValue = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator registeredStoreTypes] objectForKey: NSSQLiteStoreType];
    Class                           sqliteStoreClass = (Class)[classValue pointerValue];
    Class                           sqliteStoreMigrationManagerClass = [sqliteStoreClass migrationManagerClass];
    NSURL                           *srcURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: contextPath], *dstURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: newContextPath];
    NSMigrationManager              *manager = [[sqliteStoreMigrationManagerClass alloc] initWithSourceModel: oldModel destinationModel: self];

    @try {
        if (![manager migrateStoreFromURL: srcURL type:NSSQLiteStoreType options:nil withMappingModel:mapping toDestinationURL: dstURL destinationType:NSSQLiteStoreType destinationOptions:nil error:&error]) {
            LOG(@"Migration failed %@", error);
            return NO;
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        LOG(@"Exception: %@", exception);
        return NO;
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: contextPath error: &error]) {
        LOG(@"Error removing old database: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath: newContextPath toPath: contextPath error: &error]) {
        LOG(@"Error renaming/moving new database: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }
        LOG(@"- Context Migration: Complete");
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out, I was deleting only .db file but not .shm and .wal files. This was okay with iOS10 and below, but somehow corrupts the db in iOS11. So, deleted both the old .shm and .wal files fixed the issue.

If anyone struggling what is going wrong, this might be of some help.